# python: NOt going to new line

Tags: python, printing, server, client, newline

I've passed a string from my server to client. this string has '\n' to break lines. But in client when it receives this data, it print it in a single line, and recognize '\n' as a character.
What should I do to go to a new line in client when it sees a '\n'?

Here my code in server:

```
data4='Message Subject: %s' % (data[b'ENVELOPE'].subject)+'\n'
data5='Message Data: %s' % (data[b'BODY[TEXT]'])
data=data4+data5
connection.sendall(data.encode())
```

and here my code in client:

```
data = sock.recv(4096)
print(data)
```

Comment: use data.decode() in the client